# Mutex is not working anymore

Tags: c#, xaml, timer, mutex

I've got the following problem:

I have a Loadscreen and the MainWindow. Everytime I run the application, the Loadscreen comes first, closes after some seconds and than the MainWindow opens. My problem is, that the Mutex is not checking, if the application is already running anymore. Do you know my fallacy?

App.xaml:

```
public void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        bool Absicherung;
        Mutex Mutex = new Mutex(true, this.GetType().GUID.ToString(), out Absicherung);

        if (Absicherung)
        {
            Window W = new Loadscreen();
            W.Closed += (sender2, args) => Mutex.Close(); ;
            W.Show();
        }
        else // ...
```

Any my Loadscreen.xaml.cs:

```
public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar_Ladebalken.Value = i;
        label_Titel.Content = i + "%";

        if (i < 100)
        {
            i += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            i = 0;
            Timer.Stop();

            Window W = new MainWindow();
            W.Show();

            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Please not: **It worked before I changed "Window W = new MainWindow();" to "Window W = new Loadscreen();" --> but I want the Loadscreen to come first. In this (first) case, the Loadscreen is ignored.**

Comment: Did it just start "not working" recently? I would review what recent code changes you've made that might have caused the bug. This is simple if you're using a version control software for your project.

Comment: It worked before I changed "Window W = new MainWindow();" to "Window W = new Loadscreen();" --> but I want the Loadscreen to come first. In this (first) case, the Loadscreen is ignored.

Comment: show your timer intialization code

Comment: Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
            Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(10000);
            Timer.Start();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are closing the `Mutex` as soon as your `LoadScreen` is closed.

Before you changed the code from `MainWindow` to `LoadScreen`, it worked fine. Now, what happens is that the `Mutex` is closed when the `LoadScreen` is closed, and once the `MainWindow` opens after the `Timer` elapses, there is no `Mutex`, and another instance of the app can be opened.

To fix it, you need to move the `Mutex.Close()` logic to the `Close` event of the `MainWindow`:

```
public void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    bool Absicherung;
    Mutex Mutex = new Mutex(true, this.GetType().GUID.ToString(), out Absicherung);

    if (Absicherung)
    {
        Window W = new Loadscreen();
        // W.Closed += (sender2, args) => Mutex.Close(); remove this from here
        W.Show();
    }
    .,. Mode code
}
```

Instead, add it here: (see my comment in the code)

```
    public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar_Ladebalken.Value = i;
        label_Titel.Content = i + "%";

        if (i < 100)
        {
            i += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            i = 0;
            Timer.Stop();

            Window W = new MainWindow();

            // add the Close event handler here, and this will ensure your previous
            // logic of closing the Mutex when the MainWindow, not the LoadScreen, closes.
            W.Closed += (sender, args) => Mutex.Close(); 
            W.Show();

            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

This should fix your `Mutex` logic and keep your `LoadScreen` intact.

On another note, you should use camelCase naming convention for local variables;

```
Mutex Mutex = new Mutex();
Window W = new MainWindow();
```

Should be

```
Mutex mutex = new Mutex();
Window w = new MainWindow();
```

It is standard across C# this way.

Comment: Thanks. Thanks. Thanks. --> My problem is fixed, the application does what it should do. ;) --> and thanks for your suggestion with reference to the variables names. I will change this.